# How to parse xml from a subprocess with untangle in python

Tags: python, xml, subprocess

I'm trying to parse some xml from a subprocess with untangle in python.

```py
out = subprocess.run(["./my_executable",options], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
root = untangle.parse(out.stdout)
```

which gives my a `TypeError`:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script.py", line 64, in <module>
    root = untangle.parse(out.stdout)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/untangle.py", line 182, in parse
    parser.parse(StringIO(filename))
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes
```

when I print `out.stdout` it does in fact give the xml tags as expected but in the following format:

```
b'<root>\n  <c1>value1</c1>\n  <c2>value2</c2>\n</root>\n'
```

I tried removing the `\n` with `re.sub()` but then I get another error: `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`.

I thought this might be an encoding problem and that the [documentation](https://untangle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#encoding) would help me out, but it seems quite limited. **How can I make untangle parse a bytes-like object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode the bytes-like object to a string first.

I'm using `check_output` here to raise an exception if `my_executable` ends with a nonzero return code.

```
out = subprocess.check_output(["./my_executable",options])
root = untangle.parse(out.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Thanks @AKX. `root = untangle.parse(out.stdout.decode("utf-8"))` worked a treat. Does subprocess always return a byte-like object?

Comment: Basically yes, since a process might output binary data (though you can tell `subprocess` to decode things for you, but still, Explicit is Better than Implicit and all).